# object == object instead of object.id == object.id potential problems

Tags: c#, optimization

I have inherited a very sloppy project and I am tasked with explaining why its bad. I've noticed all over the code they have done comparisons like this

```
(IQueryable).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Facility == facility && x.Carrier == shipCode.Carrier
```

in the example above `x.Facility` is from the database and facility is from `shipment.facility` which is mapped as a complex object in nhibernate.

I would have expected to see `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Facility.ID == facility.ID`

At first I thought comparing the whole object might cause issues if the facility record was changed in the db then the facility stored in shipment would obviously be different.

After thinking about it more I realized that shipment.facility was populated from the id so it should match even if that facility record changed.

It still feels wrong to me I see this being very buggy and hard to track down? Is there somthing specifically wrong with comparing the entire object vs an id.

Comment: As far as I've always been aware (in C# and Java anyway) it's never considered a good idea to compare two objects (especially Java) when you actually mean to compare a value they hold. It's kind of hard to say in this case whether or not it's proper usage though.

Comment: I would agree with @BenAaronson comment on the answer below.  Does the `Facility` class implement IComparable or override the `.Equals` method?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Comment expanded into a full answer

Comment: Overriding `Equals` and overloading `==` is a good idea on immutable types with value semantics. But it's a bad idea on mutable types, which generally should have reference semantics, not by-id semantics.

Comment: These classes are NOT implementing any equality interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my previous comments into an answer:

I think this is actually *good* practice when the ORM allows it. I'm not experienced with NHibernate, so for the rest of the answer I'll assume that it does in fact implement equality in a sensible way (such as comparing primary keys). You should ensure this is the case, otherwise the code would be not only bad but potentially buggy.

As an analogy, forget about SQL for the moment, imagine you were dealing with a POCO which was not part of any ORM. You want to choose between the following:

**Approach 1: IEquatable**

```
public class Facility : IEquatable<Facility>
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    //The rest of the properties

    public bool Equals(Facility other)
    {
        return other.Id == Id;
    }
}
```

(You'd also want to override `Object.Equals`, but I'll exclude that for brevity)

**Approach 2: IEqualityComparer**

```
public class Facility
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    //The rest of the properties
}

public class FacilityIdsMatchEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Facility>
{
    public bool Equals(Facility x, Facility y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }
}
```

(`GetHashCode` also excluded for brevity).

Which of the two approaches is better? Well, I'd say it's **Approach 1** by a clear margin. It adheres to two important principles that **Approach 2** doesn't:

- Don't repeat yourself. In the second approach, any code anywhere trying to compare facilities would have to use the `FacilityIdsMatchEqualityComparer`. This fact, that particular equality comparison logic needs to be used, would be sprayed all over the solution, repeated every time you want to compare them.
- Single responsibility principle. Not only does every class doing the comparison need to repeat code, but that code is taking on a responsibility that doesn't belong to the class. It should be up to the `Facility` to express the implementation of equality, not up to every class that wants to use it to say that it's done by comparing `Id`s. (Yes I realise that you could just make it, say, `FacilityEqualityComparer` so that the calling classes remain agnostic about how the equality comparison is done, but the purpose of this is as an analogy with the code in the OP, where the exact comparison logic is hard coded into every comparison)

So, bringing it back to the actual question, this analogy very closely mirrors the situation you have here. It's not quite as simple as the `Facility` implementing `IEquatable`, but the principle is exactly the same: the ORM is taking its own responsibility for how equality checking is implemented, rather than pushing that responsibility out to code using it.

This means that if I'm writing code, say outside of the data access layer, I can say "I want to check if these two objects are equal, so I'll write `object1 == object2`", rather than "I want to check if these two objects are equal, and these two objects are entities, which because of the way we implement our persistence means that when I check for equality that will be converted into a SQL query, so I need to write this check as if I were writing SQL, which means I need to compare their primary keys, which either by checking attributes or maybe through my knowledge of conventions in the data access layer, I know means comparing their `Id` properties. So I'll write `object1.Id == object2.Id`".

ORMs aren't perfect, and you can't always completely abstract away the underlying SQL database, but when you can, you should!

Comment: I consider overriding `Equals` to use `Id` an anti-pattern. `Equals` should only match equivalent objects. Mutable objects with differing state, representing the same database are not equivalent in many contexts.

Comment: I'd rather add an interface `IHasId` together with an `IdEqualityComparer`. That way a caller can opt into id comparison semantics, but get normal semantics by default.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm not sure I agree with that. I guess the question is "what does it mean for two objects to have the same id but different other properties"? Since this is an ORM, I'm not sure there's any sensible interpretation of that where they're both actually different entities. Other than that it's actually two versions of the same information that have gone out of sync but that's a) more of an exceptional circumstance than the norm and b) still probably a concern you don't want every class that touches the entity model to have to get involved in. I understand your perspective though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are using but normally Entity Framework should give you an error like this if you compare the objects:

> Unable to create a constant value of type '...'. Only primitive types
>   or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Because you are sending a class needs to be converted into SQL. In any case comparing objects is not ideal for SQL code if you are trying to send a query to SQL Server.

Comment: He's using nHibernate, not EF.  While erroring is one sensible option, it's not exactly out of the question for the query provider to map this operation into a comparison of the primary keys, or even of all of the columns.  I have no idea what nHibernate choose to do though

Comment: @Servy we have to check what is the actual SQL code comes at the end then. I found it personally cheesy from a coding standpoint.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with it. Generally we make it a class's own responsibility to define how to compare it for equality by overriding `.Equals`. This seems like a similar principle- it doesn't make sense for that responsiblity to be pushed out into calling code. If there's logic "two entities are equal if their primary keys are equal" that can be generally implemented by NHibernate, that seems like exactly the right place for that logic to be, not sprayed out into any class that wants to touch entities.

Comment: @BenAaronson the way SQL code is different than C# code. Object comparison might cause confusion between the actual SQL code and C# code.

You don't say in SQL Object=Object.

But that's an NHibernate option. It is useful. I accept it.

Comment: @ToughCoder Well that's sort of my point. Code accessing entities which isn't in the data access layer shouldn't have to be "thinking in SQL" at all, unless unavoidable. That's part of the benefit you get from an ORM

Comment: @BenAaronson you are right with the ORM advantages. I wish SQL Server had lambda expressions in its core. So we don't to worry about it.

Comment: I think that the fact that this could cause problems if used again outside of an nhibernate query would cause issues is sort of a coding problem. Saying if object == object here and object.id == id here is inconsistent. I'm not sure if that is enough to make my point though.